# LOOKUP against dynamic column in Excel

Tags: excel, vlookup, xlookup

This is probably a very trivial question for an Excel expert, so I apologize in advance. I spent hours on this, but as everything in Excel -- unless one is an expert in it they will probably find quantum physics easier.

I have a workbook with a sheet which needs to pull data from another sheet. There are two lookup criteria:

1. A row-based lookup on the other sheet, which is working and finding the corresponding row.
2. In the corresponding row on the other sheet, I need to grab a value from a cell in that row based on a dynamic column name. So I have a string-based name of the column (i.e. the header; i.e. row #1), and I need to grab the value from the it based on the column's name.

Here is my lookup code and what I am trying to do:

```
=XLOOKUP(

    // Source data for row lookup (working)
    D3&H3,

    // Destination data for row lookup on other sheet (working)
    'Prices'!$A$2:$A$1048576 & 'Prices'!$B$2:$B$1048576, 

    // Not real code, but the part that I am trying to accomplish. 
    // The CUSTOM_COLUMN_NAME will come from either a formula or 
    // another cell on the given sheet, and is supposed to denote 
    // the column header name on the Prices sheet.
    'Prices'["CUSTOM_COLUMN_NAME"]:$2$1048576
)
```

(I provided the entire function just in case it would be easier for someone to rewrite it with VLOOKUP or HLOOKUP)

Hopefully this makes sense, and any help would be sincerely appreciated...

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example of 2-d look-up using MATCH and INDEX, and it will work across sheets.[image]